# ctags doesn't mark complex type statements for fortran custom types

Tags: fortran, ctags, exuberant-ctags

```
system:
mac osx catalina
Exuberant Ctags 5.8
```

call the following `mymodule.f90`

```
module mymodule
  public
  type :: thing1
     real :: a
  end type thing1
  type, extends(thing1) :: thing2
     real :: b
  end type
end module
```

then run `ctags -e mymodule.f90`
and the resulting tags file is:

```
mymodule.f90,99
module mymodulemymodule1,0
  type :: thing1thing15,27
     reala6,44
     real :: bb10,112
```

which notably is missing a definition for thing2.  I have seen ctags skip over type definitions that look like:

```
type, abstract...
type, public...
```

whatever, it seems like the parser doesn't recognize type definitions other than `type :: name`

Is there a flag that enables this, or is ctags just too outdated now to use this?  What is the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal-ctags developed at https://ctags.io can capture thing2 like:

```
$ cat mymodule.f90       
module mymodule
  public
  type :: thing1
     real :: a
  end type thing1
  type, extends(thing1) :: thing2
     real :: b
  end type
end module
$ u-ctags -o - -e  mymodule.f90


mymodule.f90,144
module mymodulemymodule1,0
  type :: thing1thing13,25
     reala4,42
  type, extends(thing1) :: thing2thing26,75
     real :: bb7,109
```

Comment: yes, best not to use software that hasn't been updated in 11 years if you can avoid it.  Thanks much, this did fix my problem, actually just using `ctags mymodule.f90` after uninstall exuberant-ctags and replacing it with universal ctags